# Is Canvas.rotate and Canvas.drawBitmap broken or is there something wrong with my code?

Tags: java, android, canvas

I'm trying to draw an image using Canvas.rotate and/or Canvas.drawBimtap, although everytime I use it, the image appears in random locations, no matter the X and Y coordinates I set it to. Here is my code, let me know if this is an issue I should report or if there is just an error in my code:

```java
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.ImageFormat;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.SurfaceTexture;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraAccessException;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraCaptureSession;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraCharacteristics;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraDevice;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraMetadata;
import android.hardware.camera2.CaptureRequest;
import android.hardware.camera2.TotalCaptureResult;
import android.hardware.camera2.params.StreamConfigurationMap;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.media.Image;
import android.media.ImageReader;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.HandlerThread;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.Size;
import android.util.SparseIntArray;
import android.view.Surface;
import android.view.TextureView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.RotateAnimation;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.UUID;


public class Photo_Page extends AppCompatActivity implements SensorEventListener {
    @Override
    protected void onStart()
    {
        super.onStart();
        GlobalClass application=(GlobalClass) getApplication();
        TextView projectnameheader = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.projectnameheader2);
        projectnameheader.setText(application.projectnameheader);
        TextView projectnameoverlay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.projectnameoverlay);
        projectnameoverlay.setText(application.projectnameheader);
        String currentDateTimeString = java.text.DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date());
        Button addcodeandnote = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addcodebutton);
        EditText entercode2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.entercode);
        EditText enternote2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enternote);
        TextView codedisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.code);
        TextView notedisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.note);
        Button savecodebutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.codesavebutton);
        TextView dateandtime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dateandtime);
        dateandtime.setText(currentDateTimeString);
        addcodeandnote.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                if (addcodebuttonpressedtimes>=1) {
                    addcodebuttonpressedtimes=0;
                    entercode2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    enternote2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    savecodebutton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
                else{
                    addcodebuttonpressedtimes +=1;
                    entercode2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    enternote2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    savecodebutton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    savecodebutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            code=entercode2.getText().toString();
                            note=enternote2.getText().toString();
                            codedisplay.setText(code);
                            notedisplay.setText(note);
                            Toast.makeText(Photo_Page.this, "Code and Note were saved successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            entercode2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            enternote2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            savecodebutton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            addcodebuttonpressedtimes=0;
                            if (code==null) {
                                codedisplay.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            }
                            else{
                                codedisplay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            }
                            if (note==null) {
                                notedisplay.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            }
                            else{
                                notedisplay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }

            }
        });

    }
    String m_path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM).getAbsolutePath();
    public String directionNESW;
    public List gpslist = new ArrayList();
    private final static String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    public Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    public SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
    public SimpleDateFormat sdftime = new SimpleDateFormat("HHmmss");
    public String time;
    public String date;
    boolean laton = false;
    boolean longon = false;
    boolean alton = false;
    public String names = "Address (GPS signal not found)";
    public double latitude;
    public double longitude;
    public double altitude;
    public boolean photowithcode = false;
    private Button btnCapture;
    private TextureView textureView2;
    public String addcodebuttonpressed = "false";
    public int addcodebuttonpressedtimes = 0;
    public String code = "Code (Empty)";
    public String note = "Note (Empty)";
    public TextView degrees;
    public TextView direction;
    public ImageView compass;
    public SensorManager sensorManager;
    public Sensor accelerometerSensor, magnetometerSensor;
    public float[] lastAccelerometer = new float[3];
    public float[] lastMagnetometer = new float[3];
    public float[] rotationMatrix = new float[9];
    public float[] orientation = new float[3];
    boolean isLastAccelerometerArrayCopied = false;
    boolean isLastMagnetometerArrayCopied = false;
    long lastUpdatedTime = 0;
    float currentDegrees = 0f;
    private ImageView compass2;
    private float[] mGravity = new float[3];
    private float[] mGeomagnetic = new float[3];
    private float azimuth = 0f;
    private float currectAzimuth = 0f;
    private SensorManager mSensorManager;

    //Check state orientation of output image
    private static final SparseIntArray ORIENTATIONS = new SparseIntArray();
    static{
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_0,90);
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_90,0);
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_180,270);
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_270,180);
    }

    private String cameraId;
    private CameraDevice cameraDevice;
    private CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSessions;
    private CaptureRequest.Builder captureRequestBuilder;
    private Size imageDimension;
    private ImageReader imageReader;

    //Save to FILE
    private File file;
    private static final int REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION = 200;
    private boolean mFlashSupported;
    private Handler mBackgroundHandler;
    private HandlerThread mBackgroundThread;

    CameraDevice.StateCallback stateCallback = new CameraDevice.StateCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onOpened(@NonNull CameraDevice camera) {
            cameraDevice = camera;
            createCameraPreview();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDisconnected(@NonNull CameraDevice cameraDevice) {
            cameraDevice.close();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(@NonNull CameraDevice cameraDevice, int i) {
            cameraDevice.close();
            cameraDevice=null;
        }
    };

    private TextView gpsdisplay;
    public TextView altitudetext;
    private LocationManager locationManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_photo_page);

        compass2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.compass);
        degrees = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.degree);
        direction = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.direction);
        mSensorManager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        accelerometerSensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
        magnetometerSensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD);
        TextView address = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.address);
        gpsdisplay = findViewById(R.id.gpscoords);
        altitudetext = findViewById(R.id.altitude);
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(Photo_Page.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(Photo_Page.this,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)!=PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
        {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(Photo_Page.this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},69);
        }

        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 10, 1, new LocationListener() {

            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                longitude = location.getLongitude();
                altitude = location.getAltitude();
                if ((alton && laton && longon) == false) {
                    gpsdisplay.setText(String.format("%.5f", latitude) + ", " + String.format("%.5f", longitude));
                    laton = true;
                    longon = true;
                    altitudetext.setText(String.format("%.2f", altitude) + " Meters");
                    alton = true;
                }
                Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(Photo_Page.this, Locale.getDefault());
                try {
                    List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
                    setUpdata(addresses);


                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            private void setUpdata(List<Address> addresses) {
                String add = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
                String city = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
                String state = addresses.get(0).getAdminArea();
                String zip = addresses.get(0).getPostalCode();
                names = add;
                address.setText(names);

            }
        });

        textureView2 = (TextureView)findViewById(R.id.textureView);
        //From Java 1.4 , you can use keyword 'assert' to check expression true or false
        assert textureView2 != null;
        textureView2.setSurfaceTextureListener(textureListener);
        btnCapture = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCapture);
        Button btnCapturewithcode = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCapturewithcode);
        btnCapture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                takePicture();
            }
        });
        btnCapturewithcode.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                photowithcode = true;
                Toast.makeText(Photo_Page.this, time, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                takePicture();
            }
        });
    }

    private void takePicture() {
        c = Calendar.getInstance();
        time = sdftime.format(c.getTime());
        date = sdf.format(c.getTime());
        GlobalClass application = (GlobalClass) getApplication();
        final File projectfile = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM), application.projectnameheader);
        if (!projectfile.exists()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Folder doesn't exist, creating it...");
            boolean rv = projectfile.mkdir();
        }
        String currentDateTimeString = java.text.DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date());
        TextView dateandtime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dateandtime);
        dateandtime.setText(currentDateTimeString);
        gpsdisplay.setText(String.format("%.5f", latitude) + ", " + String.format("%.5f", longitude));
        altitudetext.setText(String.format("%.2f", altitude) + " Meters");
        if(cameraDevice == null)
            return;
        CameraManager manager = (CameraManager)getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
        try{
            CameraCharacteristics characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraDevice.getId());
            Size[] jpegSizes = null;
            if(characteristics != null)
                jpegSizes = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP)
                        .getOutputSizes(ImageFormat.JPEG);

            //Capture image with custom size
            int width = 480;
            int height = 640;
            if(jpegSizes != null && jpegSizes.length > 0)
            {
                width = jpegSizes[0].getWidth();
                height = jpegSizes[0].getHeight();
            }
            final ImageReader reader = ImageReader.newInstance(width,height,ImageFormat.JPEG,2);
            List<Surface> outputSurface = new ArrayList<>(2);
            outputSurface.add(reader.getSurface());
            outputSurface.add(new Surface(textureView2.getSurfaceTexture()));

            final CaptureRequest.Builder captureBuilder = cameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_STILL_CAPTURE);
            captureBuilder.addTarget(reader.getSurface());
            captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_MODE_AUTO);

            //Check orientation base on device
            time = sdftime.format(c.getTime());
            date = sdf.format(c.getTime());
            int rotation = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
            captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.JPEG_ORIENTATION,ORIENTATIONS.get(rotation));
                file = new File(projectfile+"/"+(application.projectnameheader+"_"+date+"_"+time)+".jpg");
            ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener readerListener = new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener() {
                @Override
                public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader imageReader) {
                    Image image = null;
                    try{
                        image = reader.acquireLatestImage();
                        ByteBuffer buffer = image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
                        byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.capacity()];
                        buffer.get(bytes);
                        save(bytes);

                    }
                    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    catch (IOException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    finally {
                        {
                            if(image != null)
                                image.close();
                        }
                    }
                }
                private void save(byte[] bytes) throws IOException {
                    OutputStream outputStream = null;
                    try{
                        outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                        outputStream.write(bytes);
                    }finally {
                        if(outputStream != null)
                            outputStream.close();
                    }
                }
            };

            reader.setOnImageAvailableListener(readerListener,mBackgroundHandler);
            final CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback captureListener = new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCaptureCompleted(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session, @NonNull CaptureRequest request, @NonNull TotalCaptureResult result) {
                    super.onCaptureCompleted(session, request, result);
                        GlobalClass application = (GlobalClass) getApplication();
                        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                        options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
                        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
                        Bitmap dest = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getHeight(), bitmap.getWidth(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                        Canvas cs = new Canvas(dest);
                        cs.rotate(90,720 ,720);
                        Paint tPaint = new Paint();
                        tPaint.setTextSize(bitmap.getHeight()/25);
                        tPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                        tPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
                        cs.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0f, 0f, null);
                        float height = tPaint.measureText("yY");
                        cs.rotate(270,720 ,720);
                        cs.drawText(application.projectnameheader, 25, bitmap.getHeight()+545+bitmap.getHeight()/25, tPaint);
                        cs.drawText(currentDateTimeString, 25, bitmap.getHeight()+615+bitmap.getHeight()/25, tPaint);
                        cs.drawText(String.format("%.0f",currectAzimuth) + "°", 1225, bitmap.getHeight()+690+bitmap.getHeight()/25, tPaint);
                        cs.drawText(directionNESW, 1235, bitmap.getHeight()+615+bitmap.getHeight()/25, tPaint);
                        cs.drawText(String.format("%.5f", latitude) + ", " + String.format("%.5f", longitude), 25, bitmap.getHeight()+690+bitmap.getHeight()/25, tPaint);
                        cs.drawText(String.format("%.2f", altitude) + " Meters", 25, bitmap.getHeight()+755+bitmap.getHeight()/25, tPaint);
                        cs.drawText(names, 25,bitmap.getHeight()+825+bitmap.getHeight()/25, tPaint);
                        Bitmap compassbitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.compass2);
                        cs.rotate(azimuth*-1,-190,2500);
                        cs.scale(0.25f,0.25f,-190,2500);
                        cs.drawBitmap(compassbitmap, 0, 0, null);
                        if (photowithcode==true) {
                            cs.drawText(code, 25, bitmap.getHeight()+895+bitmap.getHeight()/25, tPaint);
                            cs.drawText(note, 25, bitmap.getHeight()+970+bitmap.getHeight()/25, tPaint);
                            photowithcode=false;
                        }
                        try {
                            dest.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, new FileOutputStream(new File(projectfile+"/"+(application.projectnameheader+"_"+date+"_"+time)+"___WITHTEXT.jpg")));
                        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        gpslist.add(latitude + longitude);
                    Toast.makeText(Photo_Page.this, "Saved "+file, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    createCameraPreview();
                }
            };

            cameraDevice.createCaptureSession(outputSurface, new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onConfigured(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                    try{
                        cameraCaptureSession.capture(captureBuilder.build(),captureListener,mBackgroundHandler);
                    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onConfigureFailed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {

                }
            },mBackgroundHandler);


        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void createCameraPreview() {
        try{
            SurfaceTexture texture = textureView2.getSurfaceTexture();
            assert  texture != null;
            texture.setDefaultBufferSize(imageDimension.getWidth(),imageDimension.getHeight());
            Surface surface = new Surface(texture);
            captureRequestBuilder = cameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
            captureRequestBuilder.addTarget(surface);
            cameraDevice.createCaptureSession(Arrays.asList(surface), new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onConfigured(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                    if(cameraDevice == null)
                        return;
                    cameraCaptureSessions = cameraCaptureSession;
                    updatePreview();
                }

                @Override
                public void onConfigureFailed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                    Toast.makeText(Photo_Page.this, "Changed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            },null);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void updatePreview() {
        if(cameraDevice == null)
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        captureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE,CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE_AUTO);
        try{
            cameraCaptureSessions.setRepeatingRequest(captureRequestBuilder.build(),null,mBackgroundHandler);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    private void openCamera() {
        CameraManager manager = (CameraManager)getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
        try{
            cameraId = manager.getCameraIdList()[0];
            CameraCharacteristics characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);
            StreamConfigurationMap map = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);
            assert map != null;
            imageDimension = map.getOutputSizes(SurfaceTexture.class)[0];
            //Check realtime permission if run higher API 23
            if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{
                        Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
                        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
                },REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION);
                return;
            }
            manager.openCamera(cameraId,stateCallback,null);

        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener textureListener = new TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture, int i, int i1) {
            openCamera();
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture, int i, int i1) {

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture) {

        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION) {
            if (grantResults[0] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "You can't use camera without permission", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this,mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD),
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this,mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER),
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
        startBackgroundThread();
        if(textureView2.isAvailable())
            openCamera();
        else
            textureView2.setSurfaceTextureListener(textureListener);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        stopBackgroundThread();
        super.onPause();
        mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);

    }
    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
        final float alpha= 0.97f;
        synchronized (this) {
            if(sensorEvent.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
                mGravity[0] = alpha*mGravity[0]+(1-alpha)*sensorEvent.values[0];
                mGravity[1] = alpha*mGravity[1]+(1-alpha)*sensorEvent.values[1];
                mGravity[2] = alpha*mGravity[2]+(1-alpha)*sensorEvent.values[2];
            }
            if(sensorEvent.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD) {
                mGeomagnetic[0] = alpha*mGeomagnetic[0]+(1-alpha)*sensorEvent.values[0];
                mGeomagnetic[1] = alpha*mGeomagnetic[1]+(1-alpha)*sensorEvent.values[1];
                mGeomagnetic[2] = alpha*mGeomagnetic[2]+(1-alpha)*sensorEvent.values[2];
            }
            float R[] = new float[9];
            float I[] = new float[9];
            boolean success = SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(R,I,mGravity,mGeomagnetic);
            if (success){
                float orientation[] = new float[3];
                SensorManager.getOrientation(R,orientation);
                azimuth = (float)Math.toDegrees(orientation[0]);
                azimuth = (azimuth+360)%360;

                //
                Animation anim = new RotateAnimation(-currectAzimuth,-azimuth, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,0.5f,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,0.5f);
                currectAzimuth = azimuth;
                degrees.setText(String.format("%.0f",currectAzimuth) + "°");
                anim.setDuration(500);
                anim.setRepeatCount(0);
                anim.setFillAfter(true);
                compass2.startAnimation(anim);
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

    }

    private void stopBackgroundThread() {
        mBackgroundThread.quitSafely();
        try{
            mBackgroundThread.join();
            mBackgroundThread= null;
            mBackgroundHandler = null;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void startBackgroundThread() {
        mBackgroundThread = new HandlerThread("Camera Background");
        mBackgroundThread.start();
        mBackgroundHandler = new Handler(mBackgroundThread.getLooper());
    }

}
```

My goal with this code is to draw the image of a compass on a picture that is being saved to a special file on a device. I tested this by taking a picture but I noticed that, even when I changed nothing in my code, the compass would move to a random location, sometimes not even appearing.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a lot of hard coded positions for the centre of the rotations and other items that might not be a suitable value for your actual size of bitmap backed canvas.

Probably best for the centre of rotation to be the centre of the bitmap i.e `bitmap.getHeight()/2f` and `bitmap.getWidth()/2f` and make everything relate to the size of the bitmap.

e.g.

`cs.rotate(90,bitmap.getWidth()/2f ,bitmap.getHeight()/2f);`

You also seem to do a rotation around a value that will change a lot depending on how you are holding the phone and what fluctuations there are in the magnetic field. The magnetic sensors reading are not that accurate and again the centre of this `azimuth` rotation is a weird hardcoded location (Same goes for the scale by 0.25f)

Comment: Hmm, it still doesn't really work. It stays somewhat consistent, but then if I change the code and edit the values then change the values back to what they were originally, it changes. I used ```
cs.rotate(azimuth*-1,bitmap.getWidth()/1.5f ,bitmap.getHeight()/2f);
```
then I changed it to different values, and when I changed it back, the drawing didn't even show up on the screen when it did before.